# Whitespace added when resizing page -css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

On my site http://math.byu.edu

I've been trying to make it responsive to screen size but I noticed a problem when I resize the broawser while on the page.  If I shrink and enlarge the browser multiple times the min-height is dynamically getting set to a huge number and I end up with a lot of whitespace.
I've searched my php templates and my css and I can't find anythign that owuld be causing this min-height issue. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: your `#content` box height is being controlled by JS.  Take a look into that first - Check line 21 of /js/script.js

Comment: @ntgCleaner Thank you! I found the function that is controlling it.  I'm not that good at JS but I'm sure I can figure it out in a few minute of looking at it but in case I can't, here is the code I found maybe you could take a look:`function positionFooter() {
        $('#content').css('minHeight', ($(window).height() - $('header').height() - $('footer').height() - 50) + 'px');
    }`

Comment: Great!  So you'll have to see when the function `positionFooter()` is being called.  What I **STRONGLY** suggest is getting rid of that function (just comment it out in the `$(window).resize()`) and looking into [Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

Comment: I just commented that out and it appears that my footer is still staying in proper position. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect.  The reason that script is there is when your page has basically zero content.  The footer will sneak up into the middle of the page.  I'll toss this in an answer with a little more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, just comment out the line `positionFooter()` from the `$(window).resize()` function.

The reason this theme has this script is to make sure the footer doesn't float into the middle of the page assuming the page has zero content.  When the page has zero content, there's nothing to push the footer down.  So that script is supposed to keep the footer at the bottom of the page, though it does it poorly.

For future reference, if you need a sticky footer (as it's called), I suggest using [Ryan Faits Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/).  Just wrap the content in a `main` wrapper, make sure the footer is a sibling of the main wrapper then use the supplied CSS to make it work.